# Evaluate $\int\frac{\sin z}{z^2(z^2+4)} dz$ in the region $|z - i| = 2$ using Cauchy Integral Formula.

Tags: complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to solve this using Cauchy Integral Formula for pole of order $n$ but don't understand how to deal with the multiple denominators. In other questions, I could use Partial Fraction and make it so that only 1 term of $(z-a)^n$ exists in denominator and directly apply the formula of

$$∫\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} dz = 2\pi i\cdot\frac{f^{(n)}}{n!} $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-Note that the poles inside the region are $z=0,2i$ . So write $\frac{1}{z^{2}(z-2i)}$ as partial fraction decomposition and evaluate one by one  by taking  $f=\frac{\sin(z)}{z+2i}$ .

The partial fraction decomposition is $$\frac{1}{z^{2}(z-2i)}=\frac{1}{2iz}\bigg(\frac{1}{z-2i}-\frac{1}{z}\bigg) = \frac{1}{2iz(z-2i)}-\frac{1}{2iz^{2}}=\frac{1}{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z-2i}\bigg)-\frac{1}{2iz^{2}}$$ .

So evaluate one by one by using the Cauchy-Integral formula by taking $f=\frac{\sin(z)}{z+2i}$

Otherwise use [Cauchy Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20complex%20analysis%2C%20the%20residue,and%20infinite%20series%20as%20well.) to evaluate the integral directly. Note that again the poles are $0$ of order $2$ and $2i$ of order $1$